# Set an IPMI IP in Windows 2012 Server

Tags: remote-control, windows-server-2012, wmi, wmic

I have got an IPMI adapter card on a Windows 2012 server machine (Supermicro). 
What I want to do is to set an IP (Management network) to be able to access the server via IPMI.
On a GRML live it is:

```
ipmitool lan set 1 ipsrc static
```

How do I do that on Windows... I'm very confused by this winRM stuff. and I don't want to share my confusion. I'm aware that MS exports the BMC of an IPMI card with WMIC. However there is some very advanced commandline-magic necessary as it seems ;)

Best,
Marius

p.s.: I am not allowed to create the IPMI tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to use the vendor supplied utility. Sadly e.g. Supermicro only provides Java based management application which under no circumstances should be used. They are outdated and heavily(!) insecure.

Therefore boot a GRML ISO e.g. and I set the IP using the Linux approach.